# Stream a multi-GB file to AWS S3 from ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, .net-core

I wish to create a large (multi-GB) file in an AWS S3 bucket from an ASP.NET Core Web API. The file is sufficiently large that I wish not to load the `Stream` into memory prior to uploading it to AWS S3.

Using `PutObjectAsync()` I'm forced to pre-populate the `Stream` prior to passing it on to the AWS SDK, illustrated below:

```
var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = "my-s3-bucket",
    Key = "my-file-name.txt",
    InputStream = stream
};
var putObjectResponse = await amazonS3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest);
```

My ideal pattern would involve the AWS SDK returning a `StreamWriter` (of sorts) I could `Write()` to many times and then `Finalise()` when I'm done.

Two questions concerning my challenge:

- Am I misinformed about having to pre-populate the `Stream` prior to calling on `PutObjectAsync()`?
- How should I go about uploading my large (multi-GB) file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For such situations [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) provides two options:

- [Using the AWS .NET SDK for Multipart Upload (High-Level API)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html)
- [Using the AWS .NET SDK for Multipart Upload (Low-Level API)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingLLmpuDotNet.html)

High-level API simply suggests you to create a [`TransferUtilityUploadRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) with a `PartSize` specified, so the class itself could upload the file without any need to maintain the upload by yourself. In this case you can get the progress on the multipart upload with subscribing to [`StreamTransferProgress`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLTrackProgressMPUNet.html) event. You can upload a file, a stream, or a directory.

[Low-level API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html), obviously, is more complicated, but more flexible - you can initiate the upload, and after that you do upload the next part of a file in a loop. Sample code from documentation:

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

// List to store upload part responses.
var uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();

// 1. Initialize.
var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = existingBucketName,
        Key = keyName
    };

var initResponse = s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

// 2. Upload Parts.
var contentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
var partSize = 5242880; // 5 MB

try
{
    long filePosition = 0;
    for (var i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; ++i)
    {
        // Create request to upload a part.
        var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
            {
                BucketName = existingBucketName,
                Key = keyName,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartNumber = i,
                PartSize = partSize,
                FilePosition = filePosition,
                FilePath = filePath
            };

       // Upload part and add response to our list.
       uploadResponses.Add(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));

       filePosition += partSize;
   }

   // Step 3: complete.
   var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
       {
           BucketName = existingBucketName,
           Key = keyName,
           UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
        };

   // add ETags for uploaded files
   completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);

   var completeUploadResponse = s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);     
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", exception.ToString());
    var abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = existingBucketName,
            Key = keyName,
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
        };
    s3Client.AbortMultipartUpload(abortMPURequest);
}
```

[Asynchronous version of `UploadPart`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3S3UploadPartAsyncUploadPartRequestCancellationToken.html) is available too, so you should investigate that path, if you need a full control for your uploads.

Comment: Is there any link between **uploadResponses** and **completeRequest**

Comment: it is sample code from documentation. As far as you can see, the link is in `initResponse.UploadId`, so you start the upload, got an id for it, upload all the files, and then finish the upload.

Comment: In **completeRequest** you need to add **PartyETag**

Comment: @Anjali That's strange, official samples are different - one do contain that line, other does not. I updated the code sample