# .Net Core Alternative to S3FileInfo.OpenWrite

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The AWS S3 SDK contains functionality that allows creation of a writable stream via the S3FileInfo.OpenWrite method.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

However, support for this method (and the whole Amazon.S3.IO namespace) was dropped in the .Net Core version of the SDK.

Is there an alternative method of generating a writable S3 Stream?

The TransferUtility and PutObject methods can take a readable stream objects as parameters, but neither seems to provide the ability of creating a writable S3 stream.

The following question is similar:

[Stream a multi-GB file to AWS S3 from ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264644/stream-a-multi-gb-file-to-aws-s3-from-asp-net-core-web-api)

But that use case had a pre-formed file they were looking to upload.  My use case involves a stream that will be generated at runtime.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Ended up writing my own implementation after AWS support told me that it was impossible.  I wrapped the S3 MultipartUpload in a multithreaded Stream subclass.